# Div on the right side has a dynamic height while div on the left is fixed: Side by side needed

Tags: php, css, html

Below is the PHP code for the right side of the page. This is also the dynamic part of the page. Note the section tag is created dynamically along with the content.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
?>
<section id = "rewardDet">
<br>
<p> <h2><?php echo "N".$row->pledgeAmount. " " . "or more"; ?></h2></p> <br>
<p><span> <br><?php echo $row ->title; ?></span></p> <br>

<p> <span><?php echo $row ->description; ?></span></p> <br>
<p> <span>Estimated Delivery Time: <br> <?php echo $row ->deliverytime . " ". $row ->deliveryyear; ?></span></p> <br>
<p> <span><?php echo $row ->shippingdetails; ?></p></span> <br>
<p> <span>Number of Rewards Available: <br><?php echo $row ->reward1No; ?></span></p>

</section>
```

This is the css for the dynamic right side

```
#rewardDet{
min-height:400px; /* 400 */
width:25%; /* 360 */
margin-top:0.8%; /* 10 */
margin-bottom:0.8%; /* 10 */
margin-right: 14.08%; /* 200 */
float: right;
}
```

Below is the css for the left side. This should be directly beside the right side but it is under because the divs on the right take up all the space.

```
#projDet{
min-height: 400px; /* 400 */
width: 41.67%; /* 600 */
margin-top: 0.8%; /* 10 */
margin-bottom:0.8%; /* 10 8*/
margin-left:14.08%; /* 200 */
float: left;
}
```

Please help me make them stay side by side. It's giving me a headache.

This is the code for the whole page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

<!-- about and reward title -->
<div id = "aboutProjH">
<h2> About This Project </h2>
</div>
<div id = "rewardH">
<h2> Rewards For Supporting This Project</h2>
</div>
<div id = "clearer"> </div>
<!--project pic and dynamic rewards-->
<div id = "projPic">
<img src="<?php echo $rowe ->fileToUpload;?>" width = "100%" height = "100%">
</div>

<section id = "rewardDet">
<br>
<p> <h2><?php echo "N".$row->pledgeAmount. " " . "or more"; ?></h2></p> <br>
<p><span> <br><?php echo $row ->title; ?></span></p> <br>

<p> <span><?php echo $row ->description; ?></span></p> <br>
<p> <span>Estimated Delivery Time: <br> <?php echo $row ->deliverytime . " ". $row ->deliveryyear; ?></span></p> <br>
<p> <span><?php echo $row ->shippingdetails; ?></p></span> <br>
<p> <span>Number of Rewards Available: <br><?php echo $row ->reward1No; ?></span></p>

</section>
<div id = "clearer"> </div>

<?php
}
}
}
?>
<div id = "clearer"> </div>
<!-- project details and empty divs -->

<div id = "projDet">
<span><?php echo $rowe ->projectdetails2; ?> </span>
</div>
<!--<div id = "bsideProjDet">
</div> -->
<div id = "clearer"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Please click to see the image to make things clearer.The div on the left is at the bottom of the page (projDet)and the div on the right is dynamic and takes all the space. i need them side by side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTsWo.jpg)

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant to your question. Please post the rendered HTML.

Comment: The section tags with the id rewardDet is the HTML that renders the right side of the page. The left side HTML/PHP is         <div id = "projDet">
<span><?php echo $rowe ->projectdetails2; ?> </span>
</div> @j08691

Comment: If I need to provide more information please let me know because I believe I have.@j08691.

Comment: You didn't provide the information I asked for in my first comment.

Comment: Question re-edited. I hope you have all you need now @j08691

Comment: you could create static main left and right containers first, and then append dynamic data inside those divs.

Answer (score 0):

Delete float: right; and change width to 100% for your section, create new div with width: 25%; and float: right; put no cleaner div after that.

Here is my example

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        .rewardDet{
            min-height:400px; /* 400 */
            width:100%; /* 360 */
            margin-top:0.8%; /* 10 */
            margin-bottom:0.8%; /* 10 */
            margin-right: 14.08%; /* 200 */
            background-color: red;
        }

        #projDet{
            min-height: 400px; /* 400 */
            width: 41.67%; /* 600 */
            margin-top: 0.8%; /* 10 */
            margin-bottom:0.8%; /* 10 8*/
            margin-left:14.08%; /* 200 */
            float: left;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        #a{
            float: right;
            background-color: green;
            width: 25%;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="a">
        <div class="rewardDet"></div>
        <div class="rewardDet"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="projDet"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Delete  cleaner div in while(), its moving everything after that div below it, not next to it.

Comment: projectDet has a separate Div so doing that will not help either. @MrKwe

Comment: It is, at least in my example (I have edited question). Because formating two divs one for projectDet and one for all rewardDets is much easier than trying to do that for so many divs.

Comment: Thank you @MrKew I have seen my mistake. Yes it will work if they are floating left and right in the code. I made the mistake of floating the rewardDet div to the right beside projPic . This caused a problem. Thank you once . You helped me realize my problem and solution.